# HQL Query like IN(x, y, z) but ALL(x, y, z)

Tags: java, database, persistence, hql

IN(x, y, z) performs an OR operation, I require a similar function perform an AND operation on a list input.

I have an Entity `User` who has a list of `Roles`

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Role> roles;

    ....
}
```

I require a query to extract all users that have the role ADMIN AND EMPLOYEE. Example User A is an `EMPLOYEE` and `ADMIN`, User B is an `EMPLOYEE`: User A would be selected.

The following works, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant approach:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r JOIN u.roles s WHERE r.name='ADMIN' AND s.name='EMPLOYEE'
```

I am looking for a function similar to IN, maybe something like ALL??

The following does NOT work!

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r.name IN('ADMIN', 'EMPLOYEE')
```

It is worth noting this does not work:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r.name='ADMIN' AND r.name='EMPLOYEE'
```

Comment: Analyze your query: `WHERE r.name='ADMIN' AND r.name='EMPLOYEE'` Is it possible, for a field, to have two values at the same time?

Comment: No, but `r` is a list, hence something like IN(). I understand the logic I just do not know how to implement it...

Comment: A User has a list of Roles, I need to select users with Role `ADMIN` and `EMPLOYEE`. IN() is an OR case, so if a User has `ADMIN` or `EMPLOYEE`. I think using OR will behavbe the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try your code with this

```
    String[] tags = {"ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE"};
String hql = "select u from User u " +
                "join u.roles r " +
                "where r.name in (:tags)" +
                "group by u " +
                "having count(r)=:tag_count";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("tags", tags);
query.setInteger("tag_count", tags.length);
List<User> Users = query.list();
```

Comment: IN(), does not work as it returns all users that have `ADMIN` OR `EMPLOYEE`. I need `ADMIN` AND `EMPLOYEE`

Comment: You mean return users has both 2 role ADMIN AND EMPLOYEE

Comment: Yes, in my question I have already put theat exact query you suggested, but it doesnt work. Ill update my question to make this more clear

Comment: I have updated my answer with "group by" and "having".Can you please the answer

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Although not as elegant as I was hoping for. Its a shame there isnt a simple function like `ALL(x, y, z)`